# Inconsistent static links with Next.js SSG

Tags: javascript, routes, next.js

I've created a Next.js website with the simple structure:

```
- pages
  - articles
    - [slug].js
    - index.js

- components
  - nav.js
```

In nav.js, I route all links with `next/link` as well as in `pages/articles/[slug].js` and `pages/articles/index.js` <-- The latter is an "archive" page of sorts to see all articles.

However, I can't get Link to properly point to `domain/articles/` and have the generated links in that list work properly.

With each `<Link />` I'm using the `<Link href="/articles/[id].js" as={`/articles/${id}`}>` method which works in development, but as soon as I export to a static site, issues abound.

First, setting a static link doesn't seem to work at all:

`` <Link href="/articles/index.js" as={`/articles/${id}`}> `` results in a link pointing to `domain/articles` which gives me the index of files in the generated `articles/` folder. If I manually add an `.html` to the end, then I get the page. However, the same link in a generated `articles/[id]` page link, points to `domain/articles/articles`

I think I must be doing something wrong, but I can't for the life of me figure out how I'm supposed to use the `<Link />` component to generate consistent and functional static links between pages.

Comment: Fixing this, and removing the annoying .html ends of every generated page, and we'd  have something here... Right now, next.js is unusable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issues stemmed from a quirk of Next.js deployment: It does NOT support having the site in subfolders. So `example.com/myNextSite/` will do strange things with links, while the same exported site works fine in the root `example.com`.

Answer (score 2):

**[UPDATE: Newer version of NextJS do no longer require the use of the `as` attribute.]**

First of all, the `href` attribute should not have the `.js` file suffix.

Correct hrefs for your example files would be `href="/article"` and `href="/article/[slug]"`

Secondly, your `as` attribute needs to match with the `href`, so you **can not** do for example

```
<Link href="/articles/index" as={`/articles/${id}`}>
```

since "index" does not match with the id string.

So correct tags are:

```
<Link href="/articles">
```

(Does not need `as` since it is the same as the `href`)

```
<Link href="/articles/[slug]" as={`/articles/${id}`}>
```

It should work better for you once you correct those things.